# ndnSIM installing failed => cryptoPP is present, but is not usable

Tags: linux

I have a trouble in installing ndnSIM (ns-3 module). Today I questioned about installing ns-3 but I can't solve the problem. I found another way that is installing ndnSIM.

I referenced this [URL](http://bupeanubuntu.blogspot.kr/2015/08/installing-ndnsim-on-ubuntu-1504.html) and followed instructions step by step.

but in the `ns-3/src/ndnSIM/ndn-cxx directory` when I configure(using waf build system), then I got a error message.

Yes, you're right.

it is **step 7** in the URL which I mentioned above. The following is error message.

```
Setting top to                           : /home/juhyun-park/다운로드/ndnSIM/ns-3/src/ndnSIM/ndn-cxx 
Setting out to                           : /home/juhyun-park/다운로드/ndnSIM/ns-3/src/ndnSIM/ndn-cxx/build 
Building static library                  : no 
Building shared library                  : yes 
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking supported CXXFLAGS              : -std=c++11 
Checking supported CXXFLAGS              : -pedantic -Wall -O2 -g 
Checking for program 'doxygen'           : /usr/bin/doxygen 
Checking for program 'tar'               : /bin/tar 
Checking for program 'sphinx-build'      : /usr/bin/sphinx-build 
Checking for std::is_default_constructible : yes 
Checking for std::is_nothrow_move_constructible : yes 
Checking for std::is_nothrow_move_assignable    : yes 
Checking for friend typename-specifier          : yes 
Checking for override and final specifiers      : yes 
Checking for std::vector::insert with const_iterators : no 
Checking for program 'sh'                             : /bin/sh 
Checking for library pthread                          : yes 
Checking for library rt                               : yes 
Checking for function getpass                         : yes 
Checking for rtnetlink                                : yes 
Checking for program 'pkg-config'                     : /usr/bin/pkg-config 
Checking for 'sqlite3'                                : yes 
Checking Crypto++ lib                                 : 561 
Checking if CryptoPP library works                    : no 
Checking if CryptoPP library works                    : no 
CryptoPP is present, but is not usable
(complete log in /home/juhyun-park/다운로드/ndnSIM/ns-3/src/ndnSIM/ndn-cxx/build/config.log)
```

please pay attention to last two sentences.

> CryptoPP is present, but is not usable
>
> (complete log in /home/juhyun-park/다운로드/ndnSIM/ns-3/src/ndnSIM/ndn-cxx/build/config.log)

and I also attached log file download link.

[logfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-9wOTM4WeKING1vbnVlNVFFRFk/view?usp=sharing)

What should I do to solve this problem?

---

My Development environment is that:

OS : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(Desktop Ver)
Type : 64bit
Kernel : 4.4.0-36-generic

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to build ndn-cxx standalone, after you build on the top director of ns-3 by `./waf configure`, the ndn-cxx is build also, after install it, the ndn-cxx header is installed at `/usr/local/include/ns3-dev/ns3/ndnSIM/ndn-cxx`